# This php string joining is driving me crazy!

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to prepend a "0" in front of a $_POST

```
$currency = $_POST['Currency']; // lets say 900
$currency = "0".$currency;
echo $currency;
```

It should have returned 0900 but it returns 900.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

This is the full function

```
function validate(){

        $ref = $this->input->post('Ref');
        $shop = $this->input->post('Shop');
        $amount = $this->input->post('Amount')*1000;
        //$currency = $this->input->post('Currency');
            //$currency = $_POST['Currency']; // lets say 900
            //$currency = "0".$currency;
        $currency = str_pad($_POST['Currency'],4,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM shop_validation WHERE merchant_ref = '$ref' ");
        if($query->num_rows() > 0) {

            $row = $query->row_array();

            $posts = "";

            foreach ($_POST as $name => $value) {
                $posts .= $name." / ".$value;
            }

            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO transactions (shop,amount,currency,posts) VALUES ('$shop','$amount','$currency','$posts')");


            if($row['merchant_ref'] != $ref)
            {
                echo "[NOTOK]";
                return;
            }

            if($row['merchant_id'] != $shop)
            {
                echo "[NOTOK]";
                return;
            }

            if(trim($row['amount']) != $amount)
            {
                echo "[NOTOK]";
                return;
            }

            if($row['currency_code'] != $currency)
            {
                echo "[NOTOK]";
                return;
            }

            echo "[OK]";

        }


    }
```

EDIT

This script run on Codeigniter framework

Comment: Here, that echos "0900" as expected.  Did you maybe forget to save the source file before reloading it in the browser, or something equally silly? ;)

Comment: This code prints "0900" for me. Are you testing `echo $var` or using function returned $var elsewhere?

Comment: I am sure this is something very simple and silly, but I've saved the file and tested locally and to my remote server...

Comment: Maybe the server isn't running the right file.

Comment: OP keeps trollin trollin trollin!

Comment: Glad you posted the full code — you do realize `$this->input->post('Currency')` is not exactly the same as `$_POST['Currency']`, right?

Comment: Perhaps you're using the $currency in a different context rather than just doing a simple echo and that's where the string gets converted back into a number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If what you want is to ensure that the input has a set number of digits, with leading zeros, I wrote a tip some time ago that does exactly that:

```
<?php
$variable =  sprintf("%04d",$_POST['Currency']);
?>
```

This, will echo leading zeros until the `$variable` is 4 characters long. Here are some examples:

> If `$_POST['Currency']` has a value of
>   '3' it would echo '0003'
>
> If `$_POST['Currency']` has a value of
>   '103' it would echo '0103'
>
> If `$_POST['Currency']` has a value of
>   '3103' it would echo '3103'

Which is good even if the amount of characters is longer than 4 (in your case) since it would simply ignore the function and not add anything in front of it. Hope it helped :)

Comment: Shoot, you beat me by half a minute. ;)

Comment: :) Sorry, it usually happens to me

Comment: OK this works fine but I can't understand why it doesn't work by simply concatenating the strings..

Comment: Well, if the `(string)` prefix doesn't help it, as it was suggested below, and this work, just use it. But make sure you find out the underlying problem for it could cause more problems in the future if left unknown.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the PHP's `str_pad()` function like that

```
$currency = str_pad($_POST['currency'],4,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT)
```

See [php manual](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_pad.asp) for details

Comment: If you're going to use `str_pad` remember that the second argument must be dynamic, for you can't guarantee that the user will input a 3 character string there. So I'd say replace `4` with `strlen($_POST['currency'])`. (I know you knew)

Comment: Thanks @thisMayhem you are right. I just assumed, that the whole point of padding a string is to have a fixed width string not an extra leading zero.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is auto-casting, where a variable can be a string or a number value and php guesses which one you cant. Your currency variable is being used as a string when you do string contatenation on it with the dot operator, but then when you echo it it assumes it to be an integer and throws you the integer value. You could `echo (string)$currency` or use the `str_pad()` or `printf()` function to get more useful output values.

**EDIT:** The code in the question actually works as expected for me. You must be simplifying the example and your actual output function is something other than what you present here, because in that code the auto typecasting stuff works fine.

Comment: I see in the full code you just posted that you are not echoing the variable at all, you are putting it into a database. If the problem is the data in the database this is because you have the column type set to a float or integeter or something else that saves numerical values, for which 0900 is nonsense so it saves 900. This is the CORRECT way to do things. You should save the number value, and only pad the string with formatting in your OUTPUT functions just before it get's printed to the user.

Comment: the problem is here if($row['currency_code'] != $currency). From the db I get 0900 which cannot be changed and I have to check if it is the same with the $_POST[]

Comment: @chchrist: In that case normalize the data coming from the database instead of trying to mangle your own string. You don't have to change the value in the DB, just the data type of the one you compare against. use `(intval($row['currency_code']) != $currency)` or `(floatval($row['currency_code']) != $currency)` and forget about trying to zero-pad $currency.